# Google Cloud Bucket and ReactJS app Access

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-storage

Using ReactJS I made a Build (reactJs static, npm build) and uploaded it to Google Cloud Storage Bucket, but getting a issue with the Path and Build folder files. The app (/static website) running but could not fetch the files from the bucket directory for eg the index.html & logo. (404 or 403 error )

Structure: Parent Bucket > Build folder (index.html, static folder & other files inside Build)

Any one have any suggestion on this. How to resolve this?

Do I need to create an app.yaml for GCS Bucket or any alternative?

[image: Console errors]

I have gone through the article quite similar but for AppEngine instead of Bucket. [https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-deploy-a-static-react-site-to-google-cloud-platform-55ff0bd0f509.](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-deploy-a-static-react-site-to-google-cloud-platform-55ff0bd0f509)
I have tried with app.yaml file but does not work for me.

Comment: Hello, please keep in mind that hosting a website form App Engine has nothing related to hosting a static web in a bucket. Where are you trying to host your website? if you are hosting your web from a bucket you should follow  [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)

Comment: Hi Debayan, your question it's a little bit confusing. I'm not sure if you are deploying a website on App Engine or if you are trying to host your website in a Storage bucket by itself (without using App Engine at all). Can you please clarify what you want to do?

Comment: HI Chris32, Its a reactJS static page in local environment. Its a npm local build (like and .image) and  Build is uploaded to gcs bucket. Its is running but cant able to fetch the files inside the bucket due to Path. Its explained in my description.
I want to know how to declare the path from the bucket so index.html can load the files.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same issue as mentioned by the OP. I am sharing my version of solution just in case anyone else ends up here.

As shown in the screenshots by OP, the 403 errors showed up for me because the URL of the static files in `build/static` folder was not correctly configured by the `react-scripts build` script.

Eg:

The url for `index.html` file was [https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket-name}/index.html](https://storage.googleapis.com/%7Bbucket-name%7D/index.html).
However, when the page loaded, it requested files having url https://storage.googleapis.com/static/js/main.f555c3e0.chunk.js. It should rather be
[https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket-name}/static/js/main.f555c3e0.chunk.js](https://storage.googleapis.com/%7Bbucket-name%7D/static/js/main.f555c3e0.chunk.js)

This is happening because by default `react-scripts build` assumes that your files will be served from root folder of your host.

To fix this add the following field in `package.json` of your project

```
"homepage": "https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket-name}"
```

This tells the build script that it needs to add a relative path for serving static files.
For details please refer: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Comment: Upvoted for your investigation and good explanation.

Comment: Also, if you didn't set metadata `Cache-Control` to `no-store`. It may still serve the old version of `index.html` when you try to request.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the routes of a static website stored in Google Cloud Storage, you need to assign a suffix to your objects. In other words, using suffixes is the intended way to configure your website. You can see more information in  [Hosting a static website document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#specialty-pages).

For your main index page you should set `MainPageSuffix` and for the not found page 404.html you should set `NotFoundPage` as suffix.

You can see more information on how to configure your static web [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#examples)

Comment: It worked for me by combining this answer with that of @havish

1. Set "homepage": "." in package.json
2. Set MainPageSuffix and NotFoundPage for your GCP bucket by clicking "Edit website configuration" from overflow menu. I set both as index.html (we can have different for not found page).